# Detecting which way an UITableView is scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to detect and respond when an `UITableView` is scrolling up and down? I would like to show a button at the bottom of the screen when the user scrolls down and hide it when the user scrolls up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the [`UIScrollViewDelegate.`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) Since the `UITableViewDelegate` is a subclass of the `UIScrollViewDelegate,` you can, in your view controller, set your `UITableView`'s delegate to `self.` With this, you can now implement the

```
-scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:
```

method in your view controller. If the y point of `velocity` is positive, the user is scrolling down. If the y point of `velocity` is negative, the user is scrolling up. You can use this information to set the visibility of your button.